# Visual Studio 2010 & 2012 ASP.Net debug & layout issues

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I've got Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate edition on my machine, and I've been working with ASP.NET  a lot (my job). I recently installed Visual Studio 2012, to test it out. Noticed that I had a few issues with VS 2010 after installing VS 2012, with Unit Testing etc.

Anyway, I have been debugging & testing the ASP.NET pages in 2012 to test it out. Went back to debug and test on VS 2010 and that's when it all went wrong! Sometimes it debugs, most of the time it doesn't, and when it does the layout and formatting is horribly wrong.

Tried the ASP.NET project on my employee's machines, and it runs fine and the layout is all correct. (They use VS 2010)

I've uninstalled VS 2012 completely and tried debugging and testing in VS 2010 and I still have the same issue! I also have re-installed VS 2010 twice, and yet it still does not work.

Anybody know whats wrong with it? Or what else I can do to ensure VS 2010 and 2012 stuff has been properly uninstalled before I try another re-install?

Thanks for your time..

Answer (score 0):

Create a Virtual Machine and install VS2010. In a clean install, it should work fine. Otherwise, VS2012 could have made some changes to your code. I wouldn't discard it -¿config files? ¿a new version of the bundled web server? ¿a new functionality?-.
Once you have discarded code changes due to the new version, give a try to your preferred uninstall software and delete VS2012...